# Is it possible to generate linux .rpm packages from flutter linux app?

Tags: linux, flutter

As far as I know, Flutter for linux app only targets `snap` packaging format.

Is it possible to generate `.rpm` and `.deb` (cross-linux platform) software packages from the flutter build?

Kindly post any help on how to package a flutter-linux app as RPM package

Answer (score 4):

I will also go over some of the key parts of building rpm packages for flutter applications in case the previous answer was ambiguous.

I have already written an article going into details but here I will only highlight the key parts. You can find the article [here](https://medium.com/@amin.bhst/a-complete-guide-to-building-rpm-packages-for-flutter-applications-c8cbbbab8548)

Also for simplicity of explanation, I will be using `cool-app` as an example throughout this post.

1- Run `flutter build linux` to get the Linux build inside the build folder in your project root directory.

2- Copy your `bundle` folder someplace else and there, rename it according to `app-name-version` semantic. e.g. `cool-app-1.0.0`

3- Create a .desktop file. e.g. `cool-app.desktop` will look like the following :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Cool App 
Comment=A cool app that does everything
Exec=/usr/bin/cool-app/cool-app
Icon=/usr/bin/cool-app/data/flutter_assets/assets/icon.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

change the properties accordingly and place the .desktop file inside `cool-app-1.0.0` directory

4- run `mkdir -p rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}` in your home directory.

5- copy the `cool-app-1.0.0` directory to `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES`.

Due to a problem that as the time of writing this still persists, the rpath for `lib*_plugin.so` files point to user's build tree path which results in rpmbuild failure.

6- Run `patchelf --print-rpath *` inside `cool-app-1.0.0/lib` and check the output. If the output contains a path from your home directory, run `patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN' <filename>` for all files that their rpath points to a place within your home directory. then check again. now all paths must be `$ORIGIN`. (This was the way I was able to fix it, not sure if it's the best solution)

You can check [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65400)  for further information.

7- cd into `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES` and run `tar --create --file cool-app-1.0.0.tar.gz cool-app-1.0.0` to create a tar.gz file.

8- Create a file named `cool-app.spec` inside `~/rpmbuild/SPECS` directory.
Sample `cool-app.spec` file :

```
Name:           cool-app
Version:        1.0.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Very cool app
BuildArch:      x86_64
URL:            https://github.com/CoolDev/cool-app
License:        GPLv3
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

Requires:       bash

%description
A very cool app that does everything

%prep
%setup -q

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}/%{name}
cp %{name} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}/%{name}
cp -R lib $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}/%{name}
cp -R data $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}/%{name}

desktop-file-install %{name}.desktop

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}
/usr/share/applications/
```

You could use the same template and only change `Name,Version,Summery,Release,BuildArch,URL,License,%description` and you will most likely be fine.

I went over the spec file in more detail in my article mentioned in the beginning of this post.

9- run `rpmbuild --bb cool-app.spec` to get your rpm file inside `~/rpmbuild/RPMS` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Building RPMs and DEBs is doable, but a pretty involved process. I will try to outline the basic process for RPM's as best as I can. The process of making a DEB is mostly the same with a few differences. I will stick to RPM's for now.

The main thing which is a pain is that to build packages you need specific tools which are only available on the distros. So if you want to do this cross platform (generate a RPM on a ubuntu machine for example) we need to use Docker.

1. Create a `Dockerfile` which in which we will install the `rpm-build` package which contains all tools to build RPMs.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y -q rpm-build
```

2. Build this dockerfile and remember the docker image, we will need it later.
3. Execute the following command `mkdir -p build/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}`. This will create the directory structure required for `rpmbuild`
4. Create a .spec file, this file is a config file for the `rpmbuild` command and place it in the `build/SPECS` directory. The contents of this file are very specific to the what the package has to do. RPMs are very flexible and can do lots of stuff ranging from just copying files to running complex bash scripts on the target machine to perform compilation on the target machine and perform complex installations. Here are some guides which I found useful: [package guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/), [fedora guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/), and [redhat guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/create-rpm-package).
5. Download the files you want to package, often they are distributed as tarballs and place it in the `build/SOURCES` directory.
6. Now we can execute the following command `docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build:/rpmbuild {name of image} /bin/bash -c "cd /rpmbuild && rpmbuild --define '_topdir /rpmbuild' -ba SPECS/flutter.spec"`
   I will break the command down.

- `docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/build:/rpmbuild {name of image}` - we start a container from the image we created earlier, and mount the `build` dir in which our .spec and .tar.gz are located so the container can see them. `--rm` cleans up the container after we are done since we don't need it after the first command.
- `/bin/bash -c` - this is a trick since we need to execute 2 command inside the docker container, if we don't do this our shell will thing the `&&` is meant after the `docker` command and not passed to the container.
- `"cd /rpmbuild && rpmbuild --define '_topdir /rpmbuild' -ba SPECS/flutter.spec"` - move to the mounted `build` directory and build the RPM package. the `-ba` option tells `rpmbuild` to build both the binary and source packages in case you want the source package as well.

7. If all went well your should now have an .rpm file in the `build/RPMS` and a source package in the `build/SRPMS` directory.

For DEB the process is almost the same, except you need a debian or ubuntu docker image, you use the `dpkg-deb` command to build and you need a `control` file instead of a .spec file(same purpose different format)

Comment: It is too complex to do like that, seems hard to to like that. @caveman

Comment: @Dolphin, can you give us some links to guides or tutorials that show us how to do this better? If there is some better way to do it without having to setup a dedicated build server per platform I would love to know since that would make my live easier.

Comment: I am glad to show a better way to package flutter package in liunx, but I have to say, I did not found or search a easy way to do this. I am learning to package in github actions to package into appImage or Flatpack or Snap package. @caveman